# Unit testing class library using Realm.Net

Tags: c#, realm, xunit

I'm developing a class library(`RealmClassLibrary`) which using Realm Xamarin(.NET).
I want to test the library using xunit(`RealmClassLibrary.Test`). 
And I got a `TypeInitializationException` when the library code calls `Realm.GetInstance(config)`

This exception is not thrown when I embedded class library in Windows Application(`RealmClassLibrary`.Example).

How could I fix this problem?
Is there best practice to unit test realm based project?

Any helps appreciated.

### Simple regeneration code

https://github.com/engraphia/RealmClassLibrary

#### Error log

```
RealmClassLibrary.Tests.Class1Test.testMain [FAIL]
  System.TypeInitializationException : The type initializer for 'Realms.Realm' threw an exception.
  ---- System.DllNotFoundException : Unable to load DLL 'realm-wrappers': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
  Stack Trace:
       at Realms.Realm.GetInstance(RealmConfigurationBase config)
    \\RealmClassLibrary\RealmClassLibrary\MainClass.cs(14,0): at RealmClassLibrary.MainClass.Main()
    \\RealmClassLibrary\RealmClassLibrary.Tests\Class1Test.cs(16,0): at RealmClassLibrary.Tests.Class1Test.testMain()
    ----- Inner Stack Trace -----
       at Realms.NativeCommon.register_notify_realm_changed(NotifyRealmCallback callback)
       at Realms.Realm..cctor()
```

### version

- Visual Studio (windows)

  - 2015 update3
- .NETFramework

  - v4.6.1
- Realm Xamarin (.NET)

  - 1.5.0

### project structure

- RealmClassLibrary

  - target class library
- RealmClassLibrary.Tests

  - unit test project
- RealmClassLibrary.Example

  - windows application project